# Java swing timer problems

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am having a problem with (I think) a swing timer. I wrote some code that worked fine, then moved it all over to my new computer where it promptly failed to work. I wrote a GUI class (based on JFrame) with this method:

```
public void Splash(){
    mainPanel.add(Empous.splash, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    while(Empous.splash.GetCount() < 3){
              //System.out.println(Empous.splash.GetCount());
    }
}
```

The method is called from another class. That Empous.splash guy is a JPanel class that just runs the splash animation. It does so with a swing timer. Within the splash class, the listener adjusts the contents of my frame via the following code:

```
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        counter+=1;
        if (counter==1){
            title2.setText("In Association With");
            title1.setText("El Pollo Diablo Productions");
        }
        if (counter==2){
            remove(title2);
            remove(title1);
            repaint();
        }
        if (counter==3){
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if that print statement in the first block is commented out, my program will freeze after the timer stops. If I uncomment it, the program will print out the value of the counter, then continue on right as rain. I would like to take the print statement out and have the while loop run without doing anything, but I can't do that the way this is currently behaving. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should probably create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), or at least post more code.

Comment: Please learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and stick to them when you code :-)

Comment: See [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement) for the explanation of why the print statement makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

You look to be breaking Swing's threading rules with this while loop:

```
while(Empous.splash.GetCount() < 3){
   //System.out.println(Empous.splash.GetCount());
}
```

Why do you even have this since you already have a Swing Timer which will handle this sort of thing without freesing the event thread?

For more specific advice though, yes, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Ah I figured I had outpaced my java knowledge when I ran into this. I still don't really understand some threading concepts, so I'm going to read up some more--thanks for the tips.